# Percentage Off PHP code on Woocommerce product pages showing incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress website running Elementor Pro and Woocommerce and I have the following code to surface the percentage discount of Woocommerce products on the Product page. However, there are two issues with this code:

- If the product is regular price and there is no sale price, it will
  output 100% OFF.
- Alternatively, if the product doesn't have a regular price either (nor
  sale price), it will output NAN% OFF.

Both of these scenarios are very misleading and I want to provide the best experience for my visitors.

Can you please help me with amending this code so both of the following conditions also apply to it?

1. If the product only has a regular price (and not sale price) - it outputs a different outcome for example "FULL PRICE"
2. If the product doesn't have a regular price either (or sale price) - it outputs a different outcome for example "NOT AVAILABLE"

The current code I have is this:

```
    <?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_discount_single_product' );

function display_discount_single_product(){ 
  global $product;        
        $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price    = (float) $product->get_sale_price();     
         $percentage    = round(100 - ($sale_price / $regular_price * 100));

        echo <span class=>'.$percentage.'% OFF</span></p>'

;}
```

I am running PHP version 7.4 and Woocommerce is also up-to-date.

My sincerest thank you in advance for your help - I truly appreciate it. I don't know much about PHP and this will be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if condition for $product->is_on_sale() to determine if the current product has an active sale price.

To determine if the current product has a regular price you can add a comparison for $product->get_price > 0.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_discount_single_product' );

function display_discount_single_product(){ 
    global $product;        
    $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price    = (float) $product->get_sale_price();     
         
    if ($sale_price && $regular_price) {
        $percentage    = round(100 - ($sale_price / $regular_price * 100));
        echo '<span class=>'.$percentage.'% OFF</span></p>';
    } elseif ($regular_price) {
        echo '<span class="">No Discount</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span class="">Not available</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello James - Thank you for taking the time to help me out. I tried to incorporate that code onto my original code, however, it doesn't appear to be making any difference. Are you able to support me a little further with this, please? My sincerest thank you :)

Comment: I've updated my code above to suit your exact scenario, but remember stack-overflow isn't a coding service. It's to help answer technical questions and help learn.

Comment: Hi James - thank you very much for your help. It's working as expected now. Also noted about this not being a coding service. That being said, it's great to see helpful individuals like yourself willing to take your time to do so. Have a lovely day.

Comment: Hi James - I hope you're doing well. The above was immensely helpful for me and I appreciate your help. However, there is one small update required and despite my best effort and time, I'm unable to get it working as expected. I'll need a condition that if the regular price is 0.00 (and no sale price), it prints "Free Product". I'll still need the above condition about regular price present (without sale price) still showing as "No Discount" - but with this additional condition factored in also. Without being a pain, would you be able to help me one last time please? Many thanks in regards! :)